# C#/.NET - Working with Telerik.Reporting, how to get a Telerik.Reporting.Report from .trdp

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am trying to do two things, I am trying to get a `Telerik.Reporting.Report` object from an absolute path for a given `.trdp` file and then turning that Report instance into a PDF `byte[]`. I have been fighting ChatGPT all day and it has given me useless after useless solution.

I have the following code which takes an absolute path and gets me a `byte[]` but I really need a `Report` instance before the byte array so I can adjust some properties of the report design prior to rendering it

```
public static byte[] GetReportBytes(string reportPath)
{
    var reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
    var reportSource = new UriReportSource();
    reportSource.Uri = reportPath;

    var result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", reportSource, new Hashtable());

    if (result.HasErrors)
        throw new Exception(result.Errors[0].Message);

    return result.DocumentBytes;
}
```

I would like to split this logic out into to methods:

1. public Report GetReport(string reportPath)
2. public byte[] GetReportBytes(Report report)

The reason for this is because I will have `.trdp` files in my application and I will ultimately render them as PDFs to send in an email as an attachment. But I need to be able to adjust the report design at runtime prior to render. Is this possible? I'm ok with having to update the `.trdp` with the new design or creating a serialized xml first. I just can't seem to get AI to work at all.